# Do I need to include imports in a header file with 'special types'?

Tags: c

Let's take the following example:

```
// hash.h
#ifndef _HASH_H_
#define _HASH_H_

/* A few prime number helpers */
bool is_prime(int x);

#endif
```

Because this header file uses the `bool` object, do I need to add `#include <stdbool.h>`, or is it enough for the `hash.c` file to import it. Why or why not?

Comment: As a rule of thumb - always include the immediate dependencies in the files that need them. Do not rely "indirect" inclusions.

Comment: In this particular example, I'd probably forego the use of `<stdbool.h>` altogether and just use `_Bool`.

Comment: Also, don't use `_HASH_H_` as your include guard as identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation of C.  And you left off the trailing `_` on the second line of your include guard, so it's not gonna work.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Why? To save the compiler few milliseconds including it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. In this case, because it is header for possibly a library that might be used in many projects I don't want to force the use of `stdbool.h`.  Super corner-case scenario for new code, but basically I'd do it for the same reason that they didn't introduce `bool` as a keyword in the language: so it doesn't break existing code that already defined it.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons is there a 'standard' way to do the include-guard then? For example, what 'name' would you use for the file `hash.h` ?

Comment: `HASH_H` should be really good enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your header file should `include` it if it needs it.

Otherwise you'd be relying on the `include` order of the file `include`ing your header:

```
// works
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "hash.h"
```

```
// doesn't work -- bool not defined yet when hash.h is processed
#include "hash.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: I'd also add that leaving it to be included by the source file makes you not only include it in `hash.c`, but in every source file that is going to make use of it.